# Trouble getting Axis Labels to show up in Chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Having trouble getting Axis labels to show up in Chart.js. I've followed the docs but can't seem to get the labels to actually show.

Chart code look like this:

```
<script src="http://www.chartjs.org/dist/2.7.2/Chart.bundle.js"></script>

<canvas id="m-chart-562-1"></canvas>    

<script type="text/javascript">
new Chart(
  document.getElementById('m-chart-562-1').getContext('2d'),
  {
        "type": "bar",
        "options": {
            "title": {
                "display": true,
                "text": "Test"
            },
            "legend": {
                "display": true,
                "position": "bottom"
            },
            "scales": {
                "xAxes": {
                    "scaleLabel": {
                        "display": true,
                        "labelString": "Horizontal Axis"
                    }
                },
                "yAxes": {
                    "scaleLabel": {
                        "display": true,
                        "labelString": "Vertical Axis"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "data": {
            "datasets": [{
                "label": "Number",
                "data": [10, 2, 7],
                "backgroundColor": "#7cb5ec"
            }, {
                "label": "Fatalities",
                "data": [5, 0, 1],
                "backgroundColor": "#434348"
            }],
            "labels": ["Cars", "Planes", "Boats"]
        }
    }
);
</script>
```

The chart renders fine otherwise but neither the x/y axis shows the axis label I've set in the settings.

Here's a JS Fiddle showing the same issue: http://jsfiddle.net/methnen/skfs1fjp/1/

Been banging my head against it for a little while now so appreciate any help anyone can send my way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add "[]" brackets to Axes values as below code:

```
"scales": {
                "xAxes": [{
                    "scaleLabel": {
                        "display": true,
                        "labelString": "Horizontal Axis"
                    }
                }],
                "yAxes": [{
                    "scaleLabel": {
                        "display": true,
                        "labelString": "Vertical Axis"
                    }
                }]
            }
```

Check link:
http://jsfiddle.net/skfs1fjp/7/

Comment: Hah... new it had to be something simple. Thanks a ton.